# Send info from class to another class getIntent

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

I have been trying to learn java so I can program for android. I have made an app that has 2 classes, Match and MatchResult. In Match you can push a button and it will add one to a counter. At the bottom of the page i have a button that will bring you to the next class and display the counter in a textview. Im trying to send the info trough a getIntent but its something wrong that I cant find. Here is the code:

Match:

```
    public class Match extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MATCHRESULT";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MATCHRESULT";
TextView awayGoals, homeGoals, home, away;
Button homebtn, awaybtn, gotoresult;
int homecount, awaycount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.match);

    baconAndEggs();

    homebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    awaybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    gotoresult.setOnClickListener(this);


}

 public void sendInfo(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
       intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, awaycount);
       intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, homecount);
       startActivity(intent);
    }

private void baconAndEggs() {
    awayGoals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Away);
    homeGoals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Home);
    homebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeBtn);
    awaybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.awayBtn);
    gotoresult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.matchResult);

}

public void counter() {
    awaycount = 1;
    homecount = 0;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.homeBtn:
        homecount++;
        homeGoals.setText("Lakers: " + homecount);
        break;
    case R.id.awayBtn:
        awaycount++;
        awayGoals.setText("Heat: " + awaycount);
        break;
    case R.id.matchResult:
        Intent result = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
        startActivity(result);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

MatchResult:

```
    public class MatchResult extends Activity {

TextView home, away;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.match_result);

    resultcounter();

    int awayresult = getIntent().getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, -1);
    int homeresult = getIntent().getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, -1);

    home.setText(String.valueOf(homeresult));
    Log.d("Petter", String.valueOf(homeresult));
    away.setText(String.valueOf(awayresult));
}

public void resultcounter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    home = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homeresult);
    away = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.awayresult);
}
}
```

Comment: Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY is different from EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY in above 2 activities

Comment: But dosent that show which class its from?

Comment: means? i didnt undesrtand?

Comment: ur key is same for both constant com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MATCHRESULT??

Comment: Dosent the Match infront of EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY show which class its from

Comment: no my question is dirrent i asking of both the values in match class?

Comment: Dude u haven't used sendinfo() u have declared it but not ran it during execution ... that is y its showing nullpointerexception or storing null value in second activity during getIntent()...

Comment: thestalker how should i declare it?

Comment: DIVA its the same value because its going to the same class, and in another forum they said i needed to have 2 different classes for it

Comment: ok ur usecase is start ur match activity from switch case above or sendInfo??

Comment: public void sendInfo(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
       intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, awaycount);
       intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, homecount);
       startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: ---------------OR--------------------

Comment: case R.id.matchResult:
        Intent result = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
        startActivity(result);
        break;

Comment: in case of 2nd option u wont get the int values

Comment: How do i get the int values

Comment: try to put some default values like : intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, awaycount);
       intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, homecount); in 2nd option above

Comment: Still dosent work i get -1

Comment: ok u r missing something

Comment: it seesm from above code that sendInfo is never used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, why not try scrapping your `sendInfo()` function and adding this line under your result intent instead:

```
result.putExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, awayCount);
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that code having 2 ways to call MatchResult activity hence try to use :

[hasExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String)) method to check whether that extra is passed with the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of Intent should have the context of your class. But in your case `this` refers `View.OnClickListener()`! So, just change it as in below.

```
...
case R.id.matchResult:
  Intent result = new Intent(Match.this, MatchResult.class); // Like here
  result.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, awaycount);
  result.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, homecount);
  startActivity(result);
  break;
}
...
```

Edit: You have never used sendInfo method. As far as I get, you could remove your sendInfo method and put those codes into switch case.

Answer (score 0):

I would be create a static variable shared between activities.